# Ajax загрузка товаров

Tags: ajax, json

столкнулся с проблемой листинги сайта загружаются посредством php, а товары подгружаются Ajax (Json). Но бывают ситуации, что иногда в листингах нет товаров, хотя страница загрузилась, по какой причине это может происходить и как можно воспроизвести данную ошибку? Просто ошибка появляется не всегда.

Comment: Боюсь вас огорчить, но при таком количестве исходной информации ответ может быть только такой: "Причиной такого поведения может быть, все что угодно".

Comment: Я почему то так и думал ))) Хорошо, есть ли сервисы для тестирования сайтов на аяксе, чтобы были скриншоты. Хочу смоделировать ситуацию.

Comment: просто добавьте проблемный код в вопрос.